# Procedure to insert in an unknown table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Question about Oracle - pl/sql.

is it possible to create a procedure that takes the name of the table as parameter, it retrieves the columns of the table and asks for the values of each column and then it insert the  data.
if it is possible how can i do it?

Comment: What do you mean, "ask?"  there is no user interaction in pl/sql.

Comment: so, i can't do an only procedure that inserts in all tables?

Comment: you can do dynamic sql with the DBMS_SQL packages.  Not for beginners though.

Comment: A procedure that allows you to make insertions in any table to be specified,

Comment: *"it retrieves the columns of the table and asks for the values of each column"*. This is not a good use case for PL/SQL. Stored procedures are intended for background processes. If you want to write an interactive program choose an appropriate language for writing UIs, such as Oracle Apex, JavaScript, Python, whatever

Comment: @APC ok thank you, that is what i did before, i use an appropriate language, but now just our doctor who teach us oracle tell us to do that only with pl/sql 

Comment: It is unfortunate that so many teachers of Oracle programming insist on teaching their pupils bad practices. Don't get me started on triggers :(

Comment: Anyway, let me be clearer. **It is impossible to do this in PL/SQL**: it simply lacks a capability for iterative interaction. A stored procedure takes input only when we execute it and that's it. It could be possible to solve this using a shell script to call one or more stored procedures and/or dynamic SQL it's pretty advanced stuff. I suggest you go back to your teacher and ask for some clarification: what exactly are they expecting you to do?

Comment: Thank you very mush, i tell that to the professor, now i used onother solution, i create a procedure that takes a table name in parameter and switch it to onther procedure specified for the insert in that table, thank you again you saved my time in looking for something impossible.